# Ambari Hive View: How to make Hive queries run as current user

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I finished configuring the Hive and HDFS views inside Ambari 2.4.2.. I want execute a query as a user and not a hive user.

I changed `hive.server2.enable.doAs is set to “true”` but I think is not enough because always my query execute as a hive user when I see it in ranger.
I'm looked in th eforum, that I should to configure impersonation the `authParam` look like the following:

```
hive.server2.proxy.user=${username}
```

I don't find where is this parameter to change it. knowing that I don't have a kerberized cluster hadoop, not yet I setting up the kerberos.

Thank you

Comment: pls check this out: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/37650/ambari-hive-view-how-to-make-hive-queries-run-as-c.html

Comment: where I can change the parameter hive.server2.proxy.user=${username} ?

Comment: pls follow this link: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.2.1/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/section_kerberos_setup_hive_view.html